# What is wrong with my implementation of BST insert? Java

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I am trying to understand how the BST insert algorithm works. I am doing it recursively, but I am a bit confused as to why it isn't working properly.

```
   public boolean insert(int key) {
        return insertHelper(root, key);
    }

    private boolean insertHelper(TreeNode sub, int key) {
        if (sub == null) {
            sub = new TreeNode(key);
            return true;
        } else if (sub.getData() > key) {
            return insertHelper(sub.getLeftChild(), key);
        } else
            return insertHelper(sub.getRightChild(), key);
    }
```

TreeNode Constructor

```
 public TreeNode(int data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

The issue is that when I traverse the tree to print the elements, the tree is constantly empty. There must be an issue with the insertion algorithm.

Comment: What does `TreeNode` look like? You never modify the children of a node from what I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you don't set any left and right child in any part of your code. the best technique to implement insertHelper to return TreeNode instead of a boolean value. This snippet might be helpful.

```
    private Node<T> insert(Node<T> p, T toInsert){
      if (p == null)
         return new Node<T>(toInsert);

      if (compare(toInsert, p.data) == 0)
        return p;

      if (compare(toInsert, p.data) < 0)
         p.left = insert(p.left, toInsert);
      else
         p.right = insert(p.right, toInsert);
      return p;
   }
```

Comment: Hmm. interesting, why not just return insert(p.left,toInsert) instead of assigning it to p.left? I am a bit confused about why you have to do that.

Comment: Suppose p.left is null and you send it to insert(p.left,toInsert). It creates a node inside the method but when it goes back from the recursion p.left is still null and it's not assigned to the value which is returned from the recursion. Hope this explanation is clear  otherwise I think you should read more about how passing a parameter in java works.

Answer (score 1):

It remains empty because your root is always `null`.

In java, all parameters are passed by value. 
So this code:

```
// ....
    if (sub == null) {
        sub = new TreeNode(key);
        return true;
//....
```

will create the new node, but root will not be updated.

Comment: Sweet explanation! Thanks.